# How to make electric-pair-mode buffer local?

Tags: key-bindings, minor-mode

I would like electric-pair-mode to be enabled only in the buffers where I am editing, say, Emacs Lisp.

But it seems that electric-pair-mode is a "global minor mode": if it is activated in one buffer, it automatically becomes active in all buffers.  Thus, including `(electric-pair-mode)` in the `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` does not behave in a useful way.

Is there a way to configure Emacs to only use electric pairs in some buffers?

Comment: I've never used [autopair](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs#toc1) but it may be what you need, as it is a minor mode. I'm also thinking about defining a custom minor mode and enable electric pair mode inside this custom minor mode, probably useless :\

Comment: `electric-pair-mode` is by the author of `autopair`, but included in Emacs itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a complete answer since it does not disable `electric-pair-mode`, however it does disable automatic insertion of the matching parens. You can customize `electric-pair-inhibit-predicate`. From the documentation <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`electric-pair-inhibit-predicate`<kbd>RET</kbd>

> Predicate to prevent insertion of a matching pair.

You can set it to a function which returns `t` only if the current major-mode is `emacs-lisp-mode`, something like the following

```
(defvar my-electic-pair-modes '(emacs-lisp-mode))

(defun my-inhibit-electric-pair-mode (char)
  (not (member major-mode my-electic-pair-modes)))

(setq electric-pair-inhibit-predicate #'my-inhibit-electric-pair-mode)
```

You can add any additional major-modes where you want automatic insertion to work to `my-electric-pair-modes`.

Comment: This works.  Many thanks!  I wish in the future `electric-pair-mode` will be fixed to behave as a standard minor mode, as the standard way to activate a minor mode by calling it from a major mode hook, not by writing a function that "tricks" the minor mode into not doing anything in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `electric-pair-local-mode` instead.

Answer (score 2):

here's a simple alternative (you can add it to your config file):

```
(defun my-local-electric-pair-mode ()
  (make-variable-buffer-local 'electric-pair-mode)
  (electric-pair-mode +1))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-local-electric-pair-mode)
```

Assuming `electric-pair-mode` is globally disabled (you can disable it evaluating `(electric-pair-mode -1)`), the mode will be activated only on `emacs-lisp-mode` buffers and nowhere else.

You can create similar functions for other global minor modes, such as `show-paren-mode`.

P.S. Remember to avoid enabling `electric-pair-mode` at startup or the above code won't work!

Comment: +1 Awesome trick, however I am not really sure it would work for all global minor modes

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure either. But it might since the snippet works by making the variable associated with the minor mode buffer local. Every minor mode has both a function and a variable with the same name that tracks if the mode has been activated or not. Nevertheless, I use it for `show-paren-mode` and it works OK.

Comment: Cool trick, but it seems like this is fixed in emacs 25 so the trick will no longer work, see [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS?h=emacs-25#n1395): "':global' minor mode use 'setq-default' rather than 'setq'. This means that you can't use 'make-local-variable' and expect them to "magically" become buffer-local."