# AucTeX: Disable electric-pair-mode in minibuffer during Macro definition?

Tags: latex, auctex, minibuffer, electric-pair-mode

I use Emacs 24.3.1 and AUCTeX. I switched on the `electric-pair-mode` in LaTeX-buffers. The only time I would really like to disable it in the minibuffer while inserting math-mode parentheses via the `\left` and `\right` commands. For these commands in Emacs, I use  `\` as `TeX-electric macro`.

My question would be if there is an easy way to disable the `electric-pair-mode` inside the minibuffer? Or do I maybe use an inconvenient setup for putting parentheses into equations?

Comment: The echo area is for output, not input. Do you mean the minibuffer? If so, please edit.

Comment: You say that "The only time I would really like to **disable** it is while inserting math-mode parenthesis via the \left and \right commands." Did you mean **enable**?

Comment: I would like to disable the electric pairing, when I enter the minibuffer after inserting \left inside the ordinary latex-mode buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a trick that I learned from [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5990/8430) to only use `electric-pair-mode` with specifically whitelisted modes:

```
(defvar my-electic-pair-modes '(python-mode org-mode))

(defun my-inhibit-electric-pair-mode (char)
  (not (member major-mode my-electic-pair-modes)))

(setq electric-pair-inhibit-predicate #'my-inhibit-electric-pair-mode)
```

Then you can add any mode that you want to use `electric-pair-mode` for to `my-electric-pair-modes`.

I have tested this, and **it removes the annoyance of having parens pair in the minibuffer**. In your case you can replace `python-mode` with `latex-mode` or whatever modes you want.

Comment: I accepted your solution - it worked well for my problem: Since the minibuffer has its own major-mode, electric pairs are disabled by default. Additionally, I feel like I have better control over the electric-pair-mode through implementing the list of allowed modes like you suggested - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To specifically disable `electric-pair-mode` in the minibuffer change elethan's example to use the `minibufferp` function. Below is the relevant part from my Emacs configuration:

```
;; Enable smart paring
(electric-pair-mode)

(defun pvj/inhibit-electric-pair-mode (char)
  (minibufferp))

(setq electric-pair-inhibit-predicate #'pvj/inhibit-electric-pair-mode)
```